# Show widget differently depending on if it's in the sidebar or footer

Tags: widgets, sidebar, footer

I've made a custom widget which shows thumbs of my latest videos. These thumbs are set to be 300px wide, which is the same width of my sidebar.

My problem is that i also want to be able to use it in my footer where the width of widgets are only 220px wide.

So basically what i want to do is: if the widget is shown in the sidebar use `<?php the_post_thumbnail('media-thumb-sidebar'); ?>`and if the widget is used in the footer use `<?php the_post_thumbnail('media-thumb-footer'); ?>`

Anyone know how i could do this? Thanks :)

Comment: Why not just use css to control the size of the thumbnails and the div ?  You can have different styles on the widget for example;

`#sidebar .widget{width:300px;}
#footer .widget{width:220px;}`

and obviously add styles to the img tag

Comment: Well i'm using the built in WP function "featured image" to show the thumbs, so wouldn't i have to make some kind of if statement to change the size of the thumb depending on if it's in footer or sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always get the thumbnail, but size it with CSS as Xavier mentioned.

Comment: I don't know what i was thinking, but you guys are right that works well. Thanks to you both